# How to set custom url for facebook like button

Tags: c#, html, facebook

I have added Facebook like button on my web app. 
Here the code on my html

```
 <div class="fb-like" data-href=http://someSite.com/ data-width="350" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

I looked through stackoverflow and found that i can catch curent url for html by this code

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

And now I want to set this like button for my `path` value.
Smth like this

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href=path data-width="350" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

But it doesn't work.
I looked through stackover but didn't find any answers )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

<div class="fb-like" data-href=""+path +"" data-width="350" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks )
But I've understood how to do this ) I 've used '@' <div class="fb-like" data-href=@ HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri data-width="350" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>

Comment: i think if you using MVC3 or MVc4 , you can do that syntax ,